# rospack export problem / not working on ROS Hydro

Tags: ros-hydro, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys! I was using rospack export to get the flags and compile my package outside the rosbuild system. But now, after a long time (ROS fuerte) I'm trying to do the same thing on ROS Hydro and rospack export results in nothing. If I type:
`rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags PACKAGE_NAME` I got nothing no matter what is the package.

For example: `rospack export --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags rviz`

So, anyone knows if rospack export is no longer working?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128741/rospack-export-problem-/-not-working-on-ros-hydro/) by [v3n0w](https://answers.ros.org/users/1489/v3n0w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rospack export` is working fine. E.g. you should get the necessary `lflags` for packages.

What exact `cflags` are you expecting?

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0